# How to create an image of DVD which is protected?

Tags: dvd, copy-protection

In a days I rented two multimedia DVDs from our local DVD Rental Shop. I wanted to copy them so that I could watch that film later, but to my big surprise I could not create an image of those DVDs nor copy files from them.

Is there any way to make a copy of protected DVDs?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't be backing up media that you don't fully own. It's protected for a reason.

Comment: What you're doing is illegal.

Answer (score 7):

You may use a freeware like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) or the good old [DVD Decrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/).

In ImgBurn, use the "Create Image File from Disc" option. In DVD Decrypter, click on "Mode", "ISO Read" and click the "Rip" button to create the ISO image on your hard drive.

Answer (score 4):

> I rented two multimedia DVDs from our local DVD Rental Shop. I wanted to copy them so that I could watch that film later

That's not how rentals work

> Is there any way to make a copy of protected DVDs?

[Yes](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvd.html).